# Access to external crates from module

Tags: rust

I added the dependency `rand` to my project:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.5"
```

In my `main.rs`, I have the following:

```
extern crate rand;

pub mod foo;
use foo::Foo;

fn main() {
    println!("{:#?}", Foo::new());
}
```

And in the file `foo.rs`:

```
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo { bar: bool }

impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Foo {
        Foo { bar: rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5) }
    }
}
```

And when I try to compile it, I have the following error:

```
error[E0658]: access to extern crates through prelude is experimental (see issue #44660)
  --> src\foo.rs:11:18
   |
11 |             bar: rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5)
   |                  ^^^^
```

How can I use external crates from modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extern crate` item brings crate's name into the namespace. The module has its own namespace so you need to import `rand` itself - `use rand::{self, Rng};` - because you're calling `rand::thread_rng()`:

```
extern crate rand;

mod foo {
    use rand::{self, Rng};

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Foo { bar: bool }

    impl Foo {
        pub fn new() -> Foo {
            Foo { bar: rand::thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5) }
        }
    }
}

use foo::Foo;

fn main() {
    println!("{:#?}", Foo::new());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3d924c7cd4710332de30987edcb3e3a4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Or you can import `use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};` and change the call to

```
Foo { bar: thread_rng().gen_bool(0.5) }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=154616719d8904142348a48aa6f94f58&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)